# Extraction text from image. OCR

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Pytesseract, and it's working when i use English,but when i swith to russian language. I have problem like this:

> "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface". I've tried
>   other language it also doesn't work.

## It's  my code:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
k=image_to_string(Image.open("ff.jpg"), lang="rus")
print(image_to_string(Image.open("picture.jpg"), lang="rus"))
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you need to training data for Tesseract for specific language
You need to copy language supporting file in your system
For reference you can visit the site :- https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata

Comment: Thank for your help)

Answer (score 0):

Please put the training data file(rus.traineddata) for the required language in the tessdata folder of tesseract installation.